# EEVEE Spot light

Tags: lighting, eevee-render-engine

i added spot lights to my model, but on rendering EEVEE mode they partially don't show as you can see on the attached images. could anybody give me an advice? the set up of all the spot light is the same

thanks

[image]
[image]